# Youtube Safe Search

Tags: regex, youtube

I am not sure if this question should go here.

How should i change the youtube preference cookie so that safety mode is always on?

```
PREF=f1=50000000&fms2=30000&fms1=30000&fv=10.3.183
```

This is the pref cookie and `fms2` changes to `10000` if safe search is turned off. I used regex replace to replace the text if `fms2=10000` comes in the cookie. But this doesn't seem to work. How do I change the cookie so that turning off safety-mode will turn it back on due to the cookie replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I am really not sure if I understand your question correctly. For a static string replacement from `fms2=10000` to `fms2=30000` you should not necessarily need to use Regex. "Normal" string replacement would also do it. But I guess there is more? Which language do you use?

Second: What do you mean by "that turning off safety-mode will turn it back on due to the cookie replace"? Do you want to swap the logic: "turn off" does actually a "turn on" and vice versa?

Third: Is there some additional modification in your data like URL encoding that you are maybe not aware of?

**UPDATE:**
My guess for the regex is (PCRE syntax - I am not so familiar with C++)

```
/^(?=PREF\=)(.*?(?:PREF\=|&)fms2=).*?($|&.*)/
```

replaced by

```
$130000$2
```

This would match

```
PREF=f1=50000000&fms2=10000&fms1=30000&fv=10.3.183
PREF=f1=50000000&fms2=&fms1=30000&fv=10.3.183
PREF=f1=50000000&fms1=30000&fv=10.3.183&fms2=123
PREF=fms2=123&f1=50000000&fms1=30000&fv=10.3.183
```

But it sounds like this is not only a regex problem, isn't it? Please let me know if you are facing problems or you need an explanation of the pattern.

Comment: 1: There is more. I use c++.  The other parameters of PREF may change.
2: everytime a youtube search is done, replace the PREF cookie so that fm2 always says 30000. I dont want to swap the logic, just make it ON always.
3: No.

Comment: I am using the PCRE syntax using libpcre. So I understand that. The problem is even after doing this, the youtube settings page shows safesearch is on/off according to the users settings although the cookie has been replaced.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is not the regex. Say, where or how do you manipluate the cookie exactly? On the client's HDD, in the browser's cookie store (browser addon?), as a proxy (on the client or the network), as YouTube itself (just to mention all possibilities :))?

Comment: found the error in my code. I was replacing the regex, but was not sending the modified cookies.... I know... Stupid. Anyways thanks for your help.